# Move single Git file between branches with its' history

Tags: git, git-branch, git-history

I'm using Git to manage a small repository of small shell scripts.
There's a lot of them and none justify a repository of their own, so I clump them together in a single repository.

To keep things clean, I have a few long running branches - one for scripts I'm still working on, another for scripts I've generally completed but still testing, and another for verified, trustworthy scripts. Naturally, I move them between the branches occasionaly.

I'm currently transferring the scripts between branches using `git checkout {branch} {filename}`, but this only imports the file as it currently is, leaving its' history in the old branch.

It's not terribly important, but out of curiositry - is there a way to move a single file between branches with its' history?

Thanks!

Comment: A branch is nothing but a pointer to a commit.

Comment: Git checkout doesn’t import anything?

Comment: Maybe import wasn't the right word. I'd meant copy a file from one branch to another.

Comment: @dkd6 I just would like to clear things up. Checkout doesn't copy files. It restores files in the working tree (not a branch) based on the branch/commit you give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Git, *files* don't have history.  Instead, *commits* **are** history.  The history in a Git repository is found by:

- picking a branch name (or some other label that lets you find a commit's hash ID);
- observing *that* commit, as found by its hash ID;
- using *that* commit, which contains the hash ID of one or more earlier commits, to step back to an earlier commit.

It's this stepping-back, from commit to earlier commit, that *is* the act of exploring history.  Hence the commits *are* the history.

Now, each commit contains files: in fact, each commit has a full copy of *every* file, saved in a read-only format, compressed and—since most commits mostly copy some previous commit's files unchanged—de-duplicated.  So given some set of commits that *are* history, we can have Git *filter away* some or even *most* of the history, showing us only those commits that Git thinks we'll find particularly interesting.  This is how `git log -- path` and `git log --follow -- filename` work.  They look at some subset of the actual history—some set of commits—and simply *lie to you*, using carefully selected, programmatically-controllable lies that give you the useful information.

You *must keep in mind that these are lies* that you control with options like `--simplify-by-decoration` or `--full-history`.  Otherwise you'll be fooled by the lies.  The actual history is the *commits* and Git is filtering some away.

Making a new commit leaves all the existing commits unchanged.  It *must* because no part of any commit can ever be changed, not even by Git itself.  (This is how Git manages to do the "distributed" part of being a Distributed Version Control System.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! really cleared things up for me. In that case, I assume there's no other way beside a merge or a rebase, which is understandable.